# How to display label name in autoref in place of its number

Tags: cross-referencing

Is it possible to replace the number of a chapter/section in `\autoref` with its name?

The following command will define the `\fullref` in which both of the number and name of a label will appear after "autorefname" of the label:

```
\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}}
```

However, I need no number before the name of the label.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I did not misunderstand the question, there should be the name of the chapter instead of the number.

This is exactly, what `\nameref*` does. So, there is no need of a wrapper actually, but I kept the `\fullref` as command, changed its definition. If the links should be available too, use `\nameref` instead.

**Edit**: Since the OP wants the type ('name') of the label to appear as well, the `\namecref` command from `cleveref` package is useful. It just prints the type of the label whereas `\nameref*` can be used to get the section/chapter title.

Please note, that `cleveref` should be included **after** `hyperref`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}

%\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}}

\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\namecref{#1} \nameref*{#1}}


\begin{document}
\chapter{First} \label{firstchapter}
\section{First section} \label{firstsection}


\chapter{Second}
In \fullref{firstchapter} we saw ... whereas in \nameref{firstsection}
\end{document}
```

**Edit** Here is `\fullref` version which takes the `*` into account:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fullref}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \namecref{#2} \nameref*{#2}%
  }{%
    \namecref{#2} \nameref{#2}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\chapter{First} \label{firstchapter}
\section{First section} \label{firstsection}


\chapter{Second}
In \fullref*{firstchapter} we saw ... whereas in \fullref{firstsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The \nameref command doesn't show the type of label which may be "section", "chapter", or "table" before the name of label as will be shown in \autoref.

Comment: @MehranEbrahimian: You did not wrote that `section` should appear. I will change

Comment: The `\namecref` can be changed to `\nameCref` for upper case label type names, i.e. Chapter instead of chapter

Comment: Thanks so much. Using this command, I also can easily change the name of a label type using \crefname{section}{newname}{newnames}.

Comment: Is there any way to redefine \fullref command for referencing to multiple sources, as cref{label1,label2} does?

Comment: @MehranEbrahimian: That's another question ;-) I would say `yes`